# Lengthen login session without JS

Tags: html, css

How to lengthen login session without JS (browsers HTML+CSS only and browsers with NoScript). Lengthen shall be made after clicking a link.

No JS and JQuery solutions. Only solutions without reloading site and losing form data.

Comment: to write cookies you need javascript on the client-side.

Comment: I want to send automatic  GET or POST request without JS and without new tab and without reloading of current tab. GET Reguest has cookie data. I want **not to** login (create cookie) but session make longer.

Comment: Why I got -1 for this question?

Comment: okay but you need at least php to hold the session refresh in the backend...if yo do not want ajax you need page reload in some way...

Comment: Yes, I use PHP.

Comment: okay in the meanwhile i did +1 to zeros.

Comment: and you cannot use javascript for page reload. Why?

Comment: @loretoparisi: Why - accessibility. I DO NOT use JS if there is possible solution without JS. The website is accessible also for browsers with turned-off JS and with "Noscript" extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic example of course for the php part:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = $_SESSION['token'];
  }
?>
```

and in your page you put

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300; url=/refresh.php">
```

where time is expressed in seconds so it's 5 minutes / 300 sec.

If you do a form data, to save your form data into a cookie you can do like

```
$(".esc-policy  a").on('click',function(){
   var name = $("#nameInput").val(),
   description = $("#descriptionInput").val();
   $.cookie('name',name);
   $.cookie('description',description);
});
```

and - at that point, you can use javascript to refresh session with more control:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.post('/refresh.php');
}, 1000 * 60 * 5);
```

where here time in expressed in msec.

Comment: But refresh has problem. It is automatic and possible loss of form data.

Comment: in that case you need to serialize form data into a cookie with javascript. And doing so, there is no need of meta http-equiv, but better to use javascript ajax to do a post to the refresh page as well...

Comment: without JS... I do not use JS until I don't have to. Accessibility also in browsers with disabled scripts.

Comment: Ok, but without javascript you can only use the `submit` to post form data to the `php` page. There is no other way to achieve that. With javascript you can easily save the form data into a cookie locally before submitting the form post to the `php` page...

Comment: I know it. I cannot post the data without knowledge of user. I can use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600;URL='#sessionReminder" />` to show any <aside/> with :target. It doesn't reload site. But it is not interval. In the aside user has link to mindful lengthen the session and to close the dialog (also with #hashtag). The link has target iframe and the session is lengthen but ONCE. Without scripts and without loss of form data.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. `<a href="..." target="__myIframeName__">...</a>` The GET will be send and site will be not reloaded. I do not use generally frames but there it is probably needed.